# CouchDB not accessible from the host in a VMware setup

Tags: couchdb, virtualization, virtual-machine, ports, bitnami

I setup [Bitnami's LAMP Stack](http://bitnami.org/stack/lampstack) in a VMware Workstation on windows 7 and then installed CouchDB as per [the installation guide](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Installing_on_RHEL5). Everything seems to work locally in the VM through SSH.

After hours of looking for answers, I still can't access http://ipaddress:5984/_utils from the host computer. I checked the iptables and all the ports are all opened. I also changed the bind_address to 0.0.0.0 as explained in this [serverfault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/79453/why-cant-i-access-my-couchdb-instance-externally-on-ubuntu-9-04-server) and still doesn't work. I'm setup the VM to use bridge networking with it's own IP. I also want to note that I can see the VM's apache page from my host when I access http://ipaddress, which tells me the problem might be in ports.

Does anyone know why this could be happening. The browser times out.

P.S I tried installing couchdb in AWS Free Tier but haven't succeeded. There's problems with many dependencies and the RPM package doesn't work.

Comment: TCP/IP networking of course has *many* layers, any of which could fail. Could you please append your question with the output of `curl -v http://ipaddress:5984/`. That might help identify which part of the network link is failing.

Comment: Also (another speculation), but *bridge networking* usually implies that the VM will have a *different* IP from its host, because a bridge is like a virtual ethernet cable, one end plugged into the VM, and the other plugged into your physical switch

Comment: Can you show the line from couchdb's log at [info] level that says that Apache CouchDB has started ? I want to make sure you changed the bind_address properly.  Also, try telnet localhost 5984 to see if it's listening on localhost.